# i want to know accuracy of the geocoding results

Tags: geocoding, resultset, reverse-geocoding, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

I am using the TomTom Reverse Geocoding API to obtain an address based on a given latitude and longitude. However, I've noticed that the returned address may not always be an accurate match. Is there a way to determine the accuracy rate in meters or find out how far the geocoded result is from the provided location? I would like to assess the precision of the geocoding results. Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated."

run:
Reverse Geocoding Response for Latitude: 19.067862939388316, Longitude: 73.01974981192562
{"summary":{"queryTime":19,"numResults":1},"addresses":[{"address":{"routeNumbers":[],"street":"Thane Belapur Road","streetName":"Thane Belapur Road","countryCode":"IN","countrySubdivision":"Maharashtra","countrySecondarySubdivision":"Thane","municipality":"Navi Mumbai","postalCode":"400703","municipalitySubdivision":"MIDC Industry Area","country":"India","countryCodeISO3":"IND","freeformAddress":"Thane Belapur Road, MIDC Industry Area, Navi Mumbai 400703, Maharashtra","boundingBox":{"northEast":"19.068174,73.019439","southWest":"19.067217,73.019397","entity":"position"},"countrySubdivisionName":"Maharashtra","countrySubdivisionCode":"MH","localName":"Navi Mumbai"},"position":"19.067846,73.019417","id":"DB-3I8pDDsYD5PtGxvzj6g"}]}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You can use the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance between two sets of coordinates. So compare the provided location with the returned location.

Here is a pseudocode example:

```
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # Convert latitude and longitude from degrees to radians
    lat1_rad = convertDegreesToRadians(lat1)
    lon1_rad = convertDegreesToRadians(lon1)
    lat2_rad = convertDegreesToRadians(lat2)
    lon2_rad = convertDegreesToRadians(lon2)

    # Earth's radius in meters
    R = 6371000.0

    # Difference in coordinates
    delta_lat = lat2_rad - lat1_rad
    delta_lon = lon2_rad - lon1_rad

    # Apply Haversine formula
    a = sin(delta_lat / 2) * sin(delta_lat / 2) + 
        cos(lat1_rad) * cos(lat2_rad) * 
        sin(delta_lon / 2) * sin(delta_lon / 2)
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    # Distance in meters
    distance = R * c

    return distance

function convertDegreesToRadians(degrees):
    return degrees * (π / 180)

# Example usage
lat1 = 40.7128  # Latitude of New York City
lon1 = -74.0060 # Longitude of New York City
lat2 = 51.5074  # Latitude of London
lon2 = -0.1278  # Longitude of London

distance = calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
print("Distance: ", distance, " meters") 
# -> "Distance: 5,570,222 meters
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: i am getting position in form of address

Comment: I see that there is a position in the response `"position":"19.067846,73.019417"`, which you can compare with what you provided `Latitude: 19.067862939388316, Longitude: 73.01974981192562`